# SinglarR with Angular: How to specify transport type

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, signalr.client, angular6

I am using signalr 1.0.0-rc1-update1 from npm in my Angular application.

This is how I currently connect to the hub:

```
this.hub = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(`${environment.apiUrl}operations?token=${this.user.token}`)
      .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Trace)
      .build();

    this.hub.on('GetOperations', (data: OperationGetDto[]) => {
      this.data = data;
    });

    this.hub.start()
      .then(() => {
        this.hub.invoke('GetOperations');
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        this.notificationService.openSnackBar('Error while establishing connection');
      });
```

How do I specify the transport type to be, for example, long polling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`withUrl` has an overload that takes a member of the `signalR.HttpTransportType` enum:

```
.withUrl(`${environment.apiUrl}operations?token=${this.user.token}`, signalR.HttpTransportType.LongPolling)
```